# FTP server mysterious behavior - can anyone explain why this happens?

Tags: sftp

We have an SFTP i.e secure FTP server which is perfectly like and able to login.

Using filezilla i tried to create the following file directly.

```
Employee_Details_Export_2014-11-03 03:12:11.csv
```

the FileZilla doesn't create a file and prompt an error message saying -

> Filename may not contain any of the following characters:/:*?" <>|

Whereas, the following works fine..

1. Create a test file
2. Renamed it as `Employee_Details_Export_2014-11-03 03:12:11.csv`

Not sure what is happening and what is the issue here?

Please let me know in detail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The list of characters that cannot be used in a filename includes a space, so I'm betting it's the space between the date and time in your filename.

Comment: Why it is allowed in renaming and not allowed in during creation is my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been suggested, don't use colons. From messing around, however, I'm guessing that you've found an unavoidable bug in Filezilla. The restricted character list are the characters restricted on Windows.

There is not mkfile command, so when you create a new file named "ABC.txt" you'll get something along the lines of:

> Command:  put "[PATH]\empty_file_yq744zm" "ABC.txt"
>
> Status:   local:[PATH]\empty_file_yq744zm => remote:[PATH]/ABC.txt

So what happens is Filezilla creates a file on your local machine, and then uploads it. However, Windows won't let it create a file with a colon, so it fails. However, there is a rename command, and that has nothing to do with the Windows environment. You can also create a directory with a colon without any issues since there is a mkdir command.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not related to stackoverflow, but...

this is a conditional on filezilla, not on your server, they added that to the create file

If you would like to fix this you could edit and recompile filezilla, 
this is on filezilla code on the file file_utils.cpp

Comment: general FTP issue...as the same happens via the FTP API too...Not a FileZilla issue

Answer (score 0):

Remove the colons in the filename and it should work. You're using invalid characters in your file naming convention.

```
Employee_Details_Export_2014-11-03_03_12_11.csv
```

Comment: It's likely allowed by the server OS. When you're trying to download through you need to use FTP and FTP has a different set of directives and instructions than an OS filesystem.